# Linear Transformation proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $T : \Bbb R^{n\times n} \to \Bbb R^{n\times n}$ is given by $T(A) = A-A^T$, how can I proof or find the Kernel of the above map?

Comment: Please show some effort. What did you try to do?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Use the definition: $$A \in \ker T \iff T(A) = 0 \iff A - A^T = 0 \iff A = A^T.$$